# Success Send The Email but why the c# program won't proceed to next or completed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

When Debugging Mode, after `var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(mail);`.
The rest of the program cannot run anymore.

How to solve this?

```
class Program
{
    private SqlConnection dbConnection;
    private DBSetting dbSetting;
    private UserSession usession;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {




        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(xxxxxAPIURL);
        myConnection.Open();

        Program program = new Program(myConnection, dbSetting, usession);

        string emailcontent = "";

        foreach (string targetDB in ipArray)
        {



            // Extra ItEM Type
            DataTable DT_ExtraItemType = program.GetExtraItemTypeFromTarget(SQLDBName, targetDB);

            emailcontent += "<br /> <br />Extra Item Type from " + targetDB;

            string extraitemtypemsg = "";

            foreach (DataRow DataTable_ExtraItemtype in DT_ExtraItemType.Rows)
            {
                string msg = "";

                string extra_targetdb = targetDB.ToString();
                string extra_ItemType = DataTable_ExtraItemtype["ItemType"].ToString();

                msg = "<br />In " + extra_targetdb + " ,ItemType: " + extra_ItemType;

                emailcontent += msg;
            }

            //AutoSendMessage(extraitemtypemsg, targetDB).Wait();


            DataTable DT_ExtraItemCategory = program.GetExtraItemCategoryFromTarget(SQLDBName, targetDB);

            emailcontent += "<br /> <br />Extra Item Category from " + targetDB;

            string extraitemcategoryemsg = "";
            foreach (DataRow DataTable_ExtraItemCategory in DT_ExtraItemCategory.Rows)
            {
                string msg = "";
                string extra_targetdb = targetDB.ToString();
                string extra_ItemCategory = DataTable_ExtraItemCategory["ItemCategory"].ToString();

                msg = "<br />In " + extra_targetdb + " ,Item Category: " + extra_ItemCategory;
                //extraitemcategoryemsg += msg;
                emailcontent += msg;
            }

            emailcontent += "<br /> <br />Extra ItemCode from " + targetDB;


            DataTable DT_AddNewItem = program.GetNewItem(SQLDBName, targetDB);

            foreach (DataRow DataTable_AddNewItem in DT_AddNewItem.Rows)
            {
                string addnewitem_itemcode = DataTable_AddNewItem["ItemCode"].ToString();
                string result = program.AddNewItem(addnewitem_itemcode, dbSetting, usession, targetdbSetting, targetusession);

                if (result != "success!")
                    Console.WriteLine("Fail to Create New Item " + addnewitem_itemcode + " .\n" + result.ToString());
                else Console.WriteLine(result.ToUpper() +"New Item Created : "+ addnewitem_itemcode + " .");
            }
        }

        program.AutoSendMessage(emailcontent).Wait();
    }

    public Program(SqlConnection connection, DBSetting dbset, UserSession users)
    {
        dbConnection = connection;
        dbSetting = dbset;
        usession = users;
    }


    //DataTable Extra Item Type from TargetDB and mention User to Check/Remove It manually
    private DataTable GetExtraItemTypeFromTarget(string SourceDB, string targetDB)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string sql = "select t.ItemType ItemType from " + targetDB + ".dbo.ItemType t where " +
        "not exists(select * from " + SourceDB + ".dbo.ItemType s where t.ItemType = s.ItemType) ";
        SqlCommand ExtraItemTypeCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);//using myconnection
        ExtraItemTypeCommand.CommandTimeout = 180; /*Excute Time Out Second*/
        SqlDataReader ExtraItmeTypeReader = ExtraItemTypeCommand.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(ExtraItmeTypeReader);

        return dt;

    }

    // DataTable Extra Item Category from TargetDB and mention User to Check/Remove It manually
    private DataTable GetExtraItemCategoryFromTarget(string SourceDB, string targetDB)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string sql = "select t.ItemCategory ItemCategory from " + targetDB + ".dbo.ItemCategory t where " +
        "not exists(select * from " + SourceDB + ".dbo.ItemCategory s where t.ItemCategory = s.ItemCategory) ";
        SqlCommand ExtraItemTypeCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);//using myconnection
        ExtraItemTypeCommand.CommandTimeout = 180; 
        SqlDataReader ExtraItemCategoryReader = ExtraItemTypeCommand.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(ExtraItemCategoryReader);

        return dt;

    }


    private static  async Task AutoSendMessage(string Message)
    {

        try
        {

            var client = new SendGridClient("API_KEY");


            var from = new EmailAddress("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
            var subject = "Extra Information from API_Item Master(Item, ItemCode, Item Category) Program ";
            var messagedetail = Message;
            var to = new EmailAddress("xxxxxxxx", "xxxx");
            var plainTextContent = "Hello, Email from the helper !" + messagedetail;
            var htmlContent = "<strong>Please check the Following Information:- </strong>" + messagedetail;




            var mail = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(mail);

        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Without seeing the calling code, it's not possible to provide a specific answer. Probably an async deadlock. Are you using async all the way up?

Comment: hold on i show whole code

Comment: Shivani's advice should work for you. If you're going to be using a lot of async methods, let me know and I'll add an alternative method.

Comment: please, may u show me it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue: This may be because you are blocking the UI thread. But because you haven't shared the entire code so I am not sure.

Fix: Try ConfigureAwait(false) on your call

```
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(mail).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Link: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/423#issuecomment-287853152

Comment: If it was an issue from the UI thread, wouldn't a better option be to change the (presumably button click) handler to be async?

Comment: yes, if its just one method above this thats a better option

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 7.1 language features (you may have to enable these by editing your .csproj) you can use an async Main method:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await program.AutoSendMessage(emailcontent);
}
```

To enable the C# 7.1 feature, I needed to edit my .csproj file.

1. Open your .csporj with notepad
2. Find `<TargetFrameworkVersion>SOMETHING</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
3. Add a new line below it which reads: `<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>`
4. Save your .csproj
5. You can now use async Main.